# Error in populating data when there are no existing records. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two DropDownLists and one ListBox namely: ddlYearLevel, ddlSubjects, and lstStudents.

The ddlSubjects and lstStudents are dependent on ddlYearLevel because I set the codes like this

```
protected void ddlYearLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateSubjects(int.Parse(ddlYearLevel.SelectedItem.Value));
    PopulateStudent(int.Parse(ddlSubjects.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlYearLevel.SelectedValue));
}
```

If I have existing records of Subjects for the selected YearLevel, then there's no problem.

But when I have no existing records of Subjects, that's the time the error appears stating "Input String was not in a correct format".

My problem is, how can I set the value to null if there are no records?

FYR:

```
private void PopulateSubjects(int yearLevel)
{           
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con1;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText =
        "SELECT Subjects.SubjectID, Subjects.SubjectCode, Subjects.YearID " +
        "FROM Subjects WHERE Subjects.YearID = " + yearLevel;
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (data != null)
    {
        ddlSubjects.DataSource = data;
        ddlSubjects.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
        ddlSubjects.DataTextField = "SubjectCode";
        ddlSubjects.DataBind();
    }
    else
        lblAdd.Text = "No records found!";

    data.Close();
    con1.Close();
    con1.Dispose();      
}
private void PopulateYearLevel()
{
    con5.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con5;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText =
        "SELECT * FROM YearLevels";
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
        ddlYearLevel.DataSource = data;
        ddlYearLevel.DataValueField = "YearID";
        ddlYearLevel.DataTextField = "YearLevel";
        ddlYearLevel.DataBind();

    data.Close();
    con5.Close();
    con5.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: make sure you close the connection in case there is an exception

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use Int.Parse on a value that is not an int.  I would recommend using [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) and modifying the flow of your application if there is not an parseable value available.  Example:

```
int subjectVal;
if(TryParse(ddlSubjects.SelectedValue, out subjectVal)
{
    PopulateStudent(subjectVal, yearVal);
}
else
{
    //Invalid value.  Log something, throw error, whatever.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but where am i suppose to do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have `PopulateSubjects()` return a bool: `true` if `data != null`, and vice versa.
Then you can call `PopulateStudent()` only if `true` is returned.

**Edit:**

```
protected void ddlYearLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(PopulateSubjects(int.Parse(ddlYearLevel.SelectedItem.Value)))
        PopulateStudent(int.Parse(ddlSubjects.SelectedValue), int.Parse(ddlYearLevel.SelectedValue));
}
```

Then, change `private void PopulateSubjects(int yearLevel)` to

```
private bool PopulateSubjects(int yearLevel)
```

And modify the if/else statement to add the bool

```
bool subjectsFound;
if (data != null)
{
    ddlSubjects.DataSource = data;
    ddlSubjects.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
    ddlSubjects.DataTextField = "SubjectCode";
    ddlSubjects.DataBind();
    subjectsFound = true;
}
else
{
    lblAdd.Text = "No records found!";
    subjectsFound = false;
}
```

Then `return subjectsFound;` at the end.

Comment: thanks for your response sir, but could you give me an example on how to do it because I am not that familiar with that. Thanks in advance..

Comment: sir, when I tried to change the "void" into "bool", there was a red line stating "not all code paths return a value". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would be int.TryParse or simply check `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlYearLevel.SelectedValue)` before trying to populate

Comment: like this? if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlSubject.SelectedValue)) {//error } else {Populate}

Answer (score 0):

I can also suggest that you might want to look at `ddlYearLevel.SelectedIndex` instead of `ddlYearLevel.SelectedItem`.  This might not be exactly what you want, but SelectedIndex returns the number of the currently selected item.  You could then use that to determine information about the selected item separately from examining it.